# Dataview Webpart filter by URL Path

Tags: sharepoint-designer, data-view-web-part

I want to filter my dataview by url.

Example

Path to the publishing page with the Layout:

https://domain.com/customers/exampleA/pages/default.aspx.

In the Sharepoint Designer Layout of the dafault.aspx I inserted a Dataview with a list in which the Customer information looks like this, there is also a field with the path to the Dashboard:

```
company: exampleA 
Street:street1 
pathtodashboard: exampleA
```

So I want to display only the exampleA's information in the default.aspx

What I have done, I made variables to get the URL path after "customers":

```
<xsl:variable name="custompath1" select="substring-after($CurrentUrl, 'customers/')"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="custompath" select="substring-before($custompath1, '/')"></xsl:variable>
```

So when I made the output `<xsl:value-of select="$custompath"/>` it takes the correct path "exampleA".

So how can I filter my dataview of the customer list, just to select the customer "exampleA"?

It doesn't work with the filter GUI.

Comment: You'd need to find the section in your template where the $Rows variable is defined and do something like $Rows[@company = $custompath] I believe.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit the page
2. Edit webpart property
3. Click on `Edit the current view`.
4. Filter with specific column with exampleA.
5. Save it.

If above solution is not working for you, 
you can use `Query String (URL) Filter` webpart. It will work.